# HTML: Inconsistent grid panel height?

Tags: html, css, electron

I'm a beginner to HTML, CSS and JS and am creating a text editor, much like Atom or VSCode using Electron and here is the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/chrismg12/zmbp7at3/.

I just copied the gridlayout from this pen of a CSS Grid Guide:

https://codepen.io/adrifolio/pen/GvXVgP.

The problem I am facing is visible in the fiddle, the ace text editor is going over the footer, and this is not a problem for just the text editor but for any other html element like textarea. I tried setting the height of #editor(the ace text editor in this html) as calc(inherit - 30px)(30 px bc it's the height of the footer).
If it's any help this problem had occurred to me before as well and is not only limited to this project.

I have tried setting height of #editor as:

```
calc(inherit-30px)  
calc(100vh -30px)  
calc(ato-30px)  
auto
```

and so many more that I can't think of anymore.
I have also tried setting z-index of footer to a high value but that results in only the text to be seen, but anyways even if that would work it would be a little bad as some space of the text editor isn't visible.

CSS Code for Editor:

```
#editor {  
  height: inherit;  
  font-size: 18px;  
}
```

I want it to not go over the footer

Comment: You need a space each side of the mathematical symbol, in this case the minus, e.g. `calc(100vh - 30px)`, and you can't calculate with `auto` and `inherit`, it needs to be a number, with or w/o a unit

Answer (score 0):

When you do the height calculation you should take into consideration both the tabs and footer height. Since they are 30px height each, `calc(100vh - 60px)` should do the job.